# In person meetups?

Tags: discussion

Twice other posters on SO and I have discovered that we live in the same neighborhood in a largish city. I'm guessing other users have had this experience as well. I am wondering whether in person SO meetups have ever been done? In both cases we both expressed interest in meeting up but never got around to organizing something. Would be nice if something on the site helped organize these sorts of groups for those who are interested.

Comment: This site is **not** a social networking platform.

Comment: You may ask for such in a chat room.

Comment: Um, guys... Stack Overflow has organized such meetups in the past. Let's not take the "we're not a social network" meme too far, ok?

Comment: @Pekka 웃: Them's young'ns don't know anything.

Comment: @Pekka 웃: Hey I see you managed to get the OP to undelete it. Nice work.

Comment: I'd recommend against it. You're likely to get a venereal disease. Like PHP.

Comment: @Will but there's protection available now, like Vagrant. Easier to come by than ever

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stack Overflow has done worldwide local meetups in the past, [the last time in 2012.](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/03/stack-overflow-meetup-everywhere-april-28-2012/) It was a replacement for the [Stack Overflow DevDays](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2011/06/27.html) series of events that was cancelled.

I don't know whether a rerun is planned - as far as I recall it was a big success - but it would be cool! Perhaps it's worth starting a feature request.

This June, there was an official-seeming event at [Stack Exchange's London office.](http://www.meetup.com/de/Stack-Overflow-Meetups/)

There also is a [#SOMeetup hashtag](https://twitter.com/hashtag/someetup) on Twitter but it hasn't seen any activity recently.

There was an inofficial [SOMeetup on the Philippines](http://devcon.ph/events/stackoverflow-meetup) this July.

Comment: The question mentions having a feature "on the site" for organizing these meetups, and I guess that set off all the alarms. I'd be on board with having sanctioned events on sites like meetup.com as before - after all, meetups are what *they* do best.

Comment: @Pekka 웃 Thanks for telling me to undelete.